# Como extraer array de un JsonObject en php

Tags: php

Cómo hago para extraer los mensajes de este jsonobject con foreach o for? - PHP

```
$json = {"muestra":[{"mensaje1":"1-","mensaje2":"2-"},{"mensaje1":"3-","mensaje2":"4-"}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero necesitas crear la cadena, en este caso basta con rodear el valor del *json* con las comillas simples.

```
$json='{"muestra":[{"mensaje1":"1-","mensaje2":"2-"},{"mensaje1":"3-","mensaje2":"4-"}]}';
```

Después pasar la cadena a la función [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) el cual retorna un objeto.

```
$jsonDecode=json_decode($json);
```

Por último pasas el objeto al bucle `foreach`.
*La primera key (`$jsonDecode->muestra`)  es el contenedor del array.*

```
foreach($jsonDecode->muestra as $item) {
    echo "Mensaje1 = {$item->mensaje1}<br>";
    echo "Mensaje2 = {$item->mensaje2}<br>";
}
```

[Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aace60902e6e76e30e0f2c1d198807fc59c0bda6) (Enlace externo)

Comment: elegante solución, usando un stdClass, no siempre se ve eso en las respuestas

Comment: Gracias @amenadiel

Comment: muchisimas gracias a OscarR. me funcionó. tambien agradezco a amenadie por su intento.